# "X" icon disappear from SearchView on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm handling configuration change with search, it is working but it is lead to a weird behavior, I hope I can describe it correctly:

When the screen first loads, it all working fine.

When I rotate the screen and search view is open, there are 2 cases: there is text, there isn't text.

If there isn't text - I open the search view without any text, but the "X" icon (responsible for closing the `SearchView`) disappear.

If there is text - I open the search view with text, there is a "X" icon, but when I click on in it clear the text(as it's should do in this case) but than again, the "X" icon for closing the `SearchView` is missing

So basically I just can't close the Search View.

**onCreateOptionsMenu**

```
searchView.maxWidth = Int.MAX_VALUE
if (isSearchMenuOpen) { //flag if search view active or not
    searchView.onActionViewExpanded()
    searchView.setQuery(searchQuery, false)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) // TODO: Realese on back button
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't manipulate `width` of this widget. you are setting `searchView.maxWidth = Int.MAX_VALUE` and this is causing "pushing out" of the screen the closing-X icon. delete this line

Comment: I thought it was the problem, but why is it working correctly when I first load? why is it working with the clear text "X"? also, it seems like a very common solution to expands search view on landscape mode(I'll be happy to hear other solution)

Comment: at first load there is no `SearchView`, only `MenuItem` icon. when you press this icon framework tries to draw `SearchView` with set up width, but there is already drawn `MenuItem` icon (which changes to closing-X, but still this is same `View`). when you are re-creating `Activity` and set up `SearchView` as expanded on start (with such big `width`) then framework draw this `SearchView` with all available space - at this moment nothing is drawn, so it takes whole space. next it is trying to draw `MenuItem` (with closing-X as search is opened already), but there is no space for it...

Comment: if you want greater `width` you have to calculate it, don't set `Int.MAX_VALUE` as this is waaaay bigger than any screen have pixels in any dimension

Comment: Yes I'll probably need to get the screen width and reduce some pixels,tjanks for clear explaination what went wrong